# How can I show coupon codes from my site in the search results?

Tags: google-search, search-results, rich-snippets

I've recently seen an increase in this type of search result:

[image]

But cannot find any documentation on how to show this. Does it use meta tags or Open Graph properties?

Comment: I understand you are talking about the four promotions at the bottom. I have seen this recently too. I have looked, and I didn't find anything. I am wondering if this only be available to the high-paying accounts (the premium accounts)? Now that Google has a near total monopoly on web searches, it seems that they have recently really started pushing the paid results - hardly even see organics on load anymore.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is *just* for them. They're not a huge retailer. But they must be doing some kind of meta tags somewhere or other?

Comment: Yes, you might be right in this case. I was looking and am wondering if this is a products aggregator page thing but on desktop: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product#shopping-aggregator-page

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this is a paid Google product. It is found in Google Ads as an "extension" called "Structured Snippets". You can see more here:

https://support.google.com/adspolicy/answer/6283300?hl=en-AU